# angularjs: how to access directive's scope from ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

I have a directive, which template uses a ng-include:

```
<ng-include src="filterTemplate"></ng-include>
```

the template is dynamically changed by the directive:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                switch (scope.type) {
                    case 'string':
                        scope.filterTemplate = "app/common/views/templates/gridHeaderString.html";
                        break;

                    case 'number':
                        scope.filterTemplate = "app/common/views/templates/gridHeaderNumber.html";
                        break;
                    default:
                }

                scope.filter = function () {
                    scope.filters[scope.col.field] = { value: scope.filterValue, operator: scope.filterOperator };
                    scope.searchMethod();
                }
            }
```

For instance, the gridHeaderString template looks like this:

```
<input id="test" type="text" placeholder="Filter..." ng-model="filterValue" />
```

In the filter function inside the directive, scope.filterValue does not work because filterValue exists on the child scope of the ng-include.

So in the ng-include template, I've tried to do:

```
ng-model="$parent.filterValue"
```

but that still does not work.

How do I bind the model inside the ng-include to the directive's scope ?

Answer (score 0):

hum... actually I think that was me just being dumb and I did not refresh the cache the first time.

$parent.filterValue is the way to go.